# How to write a quartz expression from for At 00:00:00am, between apr 2018 and feb 2019

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to write a Quartz cron expression for every 1 st day at 00:00:00am

from Apr 2018 to Feb 2019

I tried this with `0 0 0 ? 4-2 * 2018-2019 and 0 0 0 ? 4-2 * 2018,2019`

please help if its possible

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that Quartz triggers have the start and end time properties? You can set startTime = April 1, 2018 and endTime = Feb 28, 2019 and then you can use a simple cron expression '0 0 0 1 1/1 ? *' to get the desired schedule. You can see an example of such a trigger in the screenshot below.

[image: A simple cron expression that fires on the 1st of every month]

If you do not insist on using a CronTrigger (which is what most people intuitively tend to use), I recommend that you check the CalendarIntervalTrigger that is somewhat more suitable for these types of schedules. See an example of such a trigger in the screenshot below.

[image]